# How to learn is bottomsheet is drag to collapse or expand in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, scaffold

I want to get the state of bottomsheet drag in compose bottomsheet scaffold. How to get this drag state?

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69691630/5457853) out