# How to set half expand ratio to bottom sheet in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, android-jetpack-compose-material3

In XML we have material3 bottom sheet. It allows us to set behavior of bottom sheet. It can be updated like:

```
bottomSheetBehavior.halfExpandedRatio = 0.6
bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
```

I'm migrating project to Compose. My app used this half expanded ratio for 3 positioned bottom sheet: collapsed, half expanded, expanded. Now i'm trying to create bottom sheet like that:

```
val sheetState = rememberBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = BottomSheetValue.Collapsed
    )
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = sheetState
    )
BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {}
) {}
```

But it looks like we don't have those behavior attributes here. Can we get the same behavior as in XML with half expanded bottom sheet?

Comment: Might you can check [ModalBottomSheetState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ModalBottomSheetState) with flag `skipHalfExpanded` to achieve

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69529798/how-to-expand-bottomsheetscaffold-to-a-specific-height-at-with-jetpack-compose

Comment: @CodePoet no. I need half-expanded and then expanded states. Not just expanded

Comment: Having the same issue & wondering the same... how do we get the Bottom Sheet in compose to have a " STATE_HALF_EXPANDED " state?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. But it's a little bit of work. You basically have to provide your own implementations of the classes `BottomSheetScaffold` and `SwipeableState` as well as any related enums, classes and Composable functions used by these two.

The main points to focus on:

- provide a third value to `BottomSheetValue` for the half-expanded state
- provide a function that animates the half-expansion (similar to functions `expand()` and `collapse()` in `BottomSheetState`) as well as a property that checks if the bottom sheet is half expanded (similar to `val isExpanded: Boolean`)
- add a third `swipeable anchor` to `BottomSheetScaffold` with the half expansion value you want to achieve (check line `fullHeight - peekHeightPx to Collapsed`, here is where you want to add your custom anchor)
- handle the half expanded state in the `.semantics` block of the `Modifier` in `BottomSheetScaffold`

You might need to tweak a few more things depending on your specific requirement. It can take a while to set up everything but once it's done, it works like a charm.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of this?